# Invisible empty row inside a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I created table and filled data into this table. I don't understand why there are these empty row on Excel sheet after I copied it from table of database:

[image]

Can you help me to identify these other tables may the same error without convert it to Excel, and how to fixed these?

Comment: Those are not empty row actually. You can see Job Name for A-GR and A-BT are misplaced and printed in next row. No issue with you database or table end. This is you excel file's formating issue.You can try as LTRIM(RTRIM(JobName)) In your select statement.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

These kind of issues may happen-

During insert some of the values in your columns (Resource and JobName) had new line characters.

If this was done my mistake you can trim those out using TRIM SQL function during select or do an update of records on the table.

Or you can copy the data to NotePad++ and see if every records are displayed in their and check for new line characters or spaces, fix them if any and then copy it from Notepad++ to Excel Sheet.

Best suggestion will be to update the records correctly if it was done by mistake or do a select query with TRIM function on those columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a empty columns in some of the cells because some of the values in column RESOURCE and JOBNAME is ending with newline character i.e with \r\n.

(YOU PROBABLY 'PRESSED ENTER' AFTER ENTERING THE VALUE DURING THE INSERT OPERATION).

for eg value of A-GR in resource is ending with a newline character('A-GR\r\n').

You have to remove the new line characters to avoid the empty cells in excel sheet.

Comment: Probably, I've mistaken in typing these value. Thank you for your information